# getting error message Package operation failed

Tags: package-management

while installing any softwere or update i am getting this error

```
installArchives() failed: dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 0:

 field name `/usr/share/gnome/help-langpack/gedit/sl/gedit-plugins-modelines.page' must be followed by colon
```

Answer (score 6):

For some reasons the file `/var/lib/dpkg/available` is damaged.

Move it away, for example with

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/available /var/lib/dpkg/available.bak
```

If there is a file `/var/lib/dpkg/available-old` try if this one works:

```
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/available-old /var/lib/dpkg/available
```

If installing software works now you are done.

If it still doesn't work run

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/available 
sudo sudo touch /var/lib/dpkg/available  
sudo sh -c 'for i in /var/lib/apt/lists/*_Packages; do dpkg --merge-avail "$i"; done'
```

to create a new file.

Comment: Thanks i used  last option to create new file and everything is ok now thanks a lot

Comment: Copying the old file worked fine for me - many thanks.