# 'E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)' while updating

Tags: 11.10, installation, software-center, update-manager, dpkg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [getting error message Package operation failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98157/getting-error-message-package-operation-failed)

Terminal

```
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 0:
 field name `/usr/share/gnome/help-langpack/evince/bg/duplex-11pages.page' must be followed by colon
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Ubuntu Software Center

```
installArchives() failed: dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 0:
 field name `/usr/share/gnome/help-langpack/evince/bg/duplex-11pages.page' must be followed by colon
Error in function:
```

Comment: Are you upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04?  Or are you just updating 11.10?

Comment: Chris, No I'm not upgrading to 12.04. I'm currently using Ubuntu 11.10 and the update manager showed 5 updates. After clicking "install updates" an error msg comes up saying "Package operation failed" installArchives() failed: dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 0:
 field name `/usr/share/gnome/help-langpack/evince/bg/duplex-11pages.page' must be followed by colon

Comment: The same goes with trying to install any software. I get the same error code

installArchives() failed: dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 0:
 field name `/usr/share/gnome/help-langpack/evince/bg/duplex-11pages.page' must be followed by colon